# A converter that converts a string to a different string

Tags: python-3.x

Okay it's really complicated to explain, input required, user is typing his input and then it prints what he said but each character is replaced with another character (not random, each symbol will equal a symbol, for example "a" will be "9". Like this) so if I put the input "a" it will return "9", let's say "b" = "5" and "c" = "$". So my if my input is abc (can be ABC it doesn't matter, it will do the .upper), it will print "95$". Like an encoder, each symbol will equal to something and then it will know what to return. I wasn't really sure if it is clear, let me know what isn't clear and I'll make sure to respond as quickly as possible. I tried doing some things but it's a bit hard, I'm still a beginner and that's how I learn. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**
A better example:
asking for input,
input: abc,
output: 95$

Comment: What's the relationship between characters and the characters that replace them?  Do you have a `dict` that maps those characters?  What happens to characters that you don't know the replacement for?

Comment: Do you have an exhaustive list of the string encodings/mappings? Showing us some examples might allow us to see the patterns better.

Comment: All you need is a map (python dict) of characters to their encoded values. Take input, lower case it, put it into the map and you will have your value. For more than one character `split` the input string and iterate over the array building a new string with the mapped values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary (`dict`).

```
my_encoder = dict({"a":"9", "b":"5","c":"$"})
```

How to use:

```
value = my_encoder["a"]
print(value) # 9
```

In your case for a input of `abc`:

```
input = "abc"
encoded_input = ""

for character in input:
  encoded_input = encoded_input + my_encoder[character]

print(encoded_input) # 95$
```

Comment: The `str` class has a built-in method for that. `str#translate`

Answer (score 0):

Python `str`s have a built-in `translate` function. Pass in a dictionary of `{<code point>:<replacement>}`. In the case of what you've shown, you could do:

```
print(input().upper().translate({65:'9',66:'5',67:'$'}))
```

If you have a lot of mappings to do, you can use the `str#maketrans` static method with two strings of equal length.

```
trans = str.maketrans('ABC', '95$')
print(input().upper().translate(trans))
```